# SSIS send email task is not working what am i doing wrong?

Tags: sql-server, csv, email, ssis, task

I am simply trying to send an email when the process is done running.

I have a simple CSV file transferring to CSV file and I have a send email task with the server name smtp.gmail.com and the port option is not there.

I have inputted all the information and getting this error when I run the whole package.

The error is this:

> Error: 0xC002F304 at Send Mail Task, Send Mail Task: An error occurred with the following error message: "Failure sending mail. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.125.195.109:25". Task failed: Send Mail Task

Comment: Check "Delay Validation" property of Send Mail Task, set this from False to TRUE

Comment: Has the task ever worked? Are you certain that is the correct IP for your mail server? Does the mail server allow mail to be sent from your computer (Exchange admins deny access to non-email clients {outlook} sending from desktops to prevent automated spamming attacks)

Comment: the sendmail component is very generic.   you'll want a script task to customize the parts/ports for sending via gmail: [example](http://etlscrapbook.blogspot.com/2017/02/send-mail-from-gmail-smtp-server-by.html?m=1)

Comment: I have tried using your script, I got the following error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: @billinkc this task has never worked for me before.

Comment: @CR241 I have done this and still does not work

Comment: It seems you've tried a Send Mail Task, a Script Task to send email, and configuring SQL Server to send mail. These appear to all have challenges communicating with your mail server which strong implies that either you have invalid connection information or the server does not allow ad hoc programs to send email.

Comment: Try pinging the SMTP server. You could be missing the port.

Comment: @KeithL I have tried using a script and that works now, I also tried using the test mail in the ssms database mail and it seems to also work not. But I am still not able to use the send mail task (I do not see an option to fill in the port, I am using smtp.gmail.com as the stmp server)

Comment: I googled this "send mail port gmail" and found Port: 465 (SSL required) or 587 (TLS required) in about 2 seconds

Comment: @KeithL I do know the ports but there is no option to put in the ports in the send email popup it just asks for the smtp server, from, to, subject

Comment: [Server Name]:PortNumber

Comment: Ther is only a tab for the server name, there is no tab for the port

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not configure the mail in `Database Mail`,please check below snapshot for your reference how to configure.

**Open SQL SERVER>MANGEMENT>Database Mail>Right Click and Open configure database mail**

[image]

and then set your Email,`SMTP Account` and then only you will able to send alert using `SendDB Mail Task`
[image]

Once you configure this in `SQL Server` it will definitly work for you.

Comment: I  have also done this on sql server and the test email does not go out

Comment: This answer shows how to set up SQL Server for database mail. The original question is asking how to use the SSIS component Send Mail which does not route through sp_send_dbmail. It uses a connection directly to the mail server

Comment: @billinkc I have also tried using a script to send an email but I still get an error